Исключение в серверном приложении
У меня клиентское приложение на react. js и webapi asp. net. Все работало до того момента, как мне не понадобилось импортировать данные из файла. На клиенте я использовал html input type=file. В момент нажатия любой кнопки в диалоговом окне выбора файла, выбрать или отменить, у меня закрывается web.api. при этом никаких ошибок ни на клиенте ни на сервере не вылазит. Я сломал весь мозг, попробовал тоже на пустом проекте. Использую  .Net 5
Все это происходит в режиме разработке. Клиента запускаю через VSC, сервер через Visual Studio

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Очень странно, но на другом компе такой проблемы нет
